# Appending a dictionary to another dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote this piece of code and I need some help to debug it. I would have to say that I have read some similar topic in this regard in this website but it could not help me to debug my code :)

OUTPUT:

```
Number of max devices per route: 4
Number of routes: 2
Level of mobility: 2
routes  at T 0 : {0: [28, 14, 7, 4], 1: [22, 0]}
routes  at T 1 : {0: [29, 20, 28], 1: [28]}
{0: {0: [29, 20, 28], 1: [28]}, 1: {0: [29, 20, 28], 1: [28]}}
```

My problem is that i want to have output like this:

```
{ 0:{0: [28, 14, 7, 4], 1: [22, 0]} , 1: {0: [29, 20, 28], 1: [28]},}
```

but, I do not know why the last dictionary is repeated again in new dictionary. I tried to debug it but i was unable to be successful. So, how can I append a dictionary to another dictionary in a loop ?

```
class myClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Class constructor.
        """

        self.no_devices = input("Number of max devices per route: ")
        self.no_routes = input("Number of routes: ")
        self.mob=input("Level of mobility: ")
        self.all_routes={}
        self.routes = {}

        self.arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...,29] 

        for j in xrange(self.mob):
            for i in range(self.no_routes):
                random.shuffle(self.arr)                                          
                self.routes[i] = list(self.arr[0: random.randint(1,self.no_devices)])          
                self.all_routes[j]=self.routes


            print "routes  at T" ,j, ":" ,self.routes


        print self.all_routes
```

Comment: How `self.arr` is initialized. It seems to be shuffled before any value is assigned to it? Its very difficult to debug you code without complete information.

Comment: hi, thank you for reply, self.arr is an array including number from 0 to 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @shaktimaan indicated `self.routes` in each iteration of the loop is overwritten, and `self.all_routes` keeps only a reference to `self.routes`. I modified the code, once to make it work with python 3.4 (i.e. version of python I have, sorry, I don't work with 2.x now) and also to fix the overwriting problem.

```
import random

class myClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Class constructor.
        """

        self.no_devices = int(input("Number of max devices per route: "))
        self.no_routes = int(input("Number of routes: "))
        self.mob = int(input("Level of mobility: "))
        self.all_routes={}


        self.arr = list(range(0,30))

        for j in range(self.mob):
            routes = {}
            for i in range(self.no_routes):
                random.shuffle(self.arr)                                          
                routes[i] = list(self.arr[0: random.randint(1,self.no_devices)])          
                self.all_routes[j]=routes


            print("routes  at T" ,j, ":" ,routes)


        print(self.all_routes)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClassName()
```

Example output:

```
Number of max devices per route: 4
Number of routes: 2
2Level of mobility: 
routes  at T 0 : {0: [0, 10], 1: [22, 14]}
routes  at T 1 : {0: [16], 1: [22, 3, 5, 17]}
{0: {0: [0, 10], 1: [22, 14]}, 1: {0: [16], 1: [22, 3, 5, 17]}}
```

Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: @user3671039 Glad I could help. If the answer was satisfactory, accepting it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:
`orig_dict.update(new_dict)`

Note: If both dictionaries have some similar keys,the values will be picked from the `new_dict`

## Edit:

I think the problem you might be having is because you are overwriting `dict` with `list`(`routes` & `all_routes`)

Comment: tnx for reply. But i do not want update it, i wanna append the first and  second route dictionaries to new one.  in each iteration i have a new route dictionary and i want to append all of the in new dictionary containing all...